# ngModel formatters change the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Having an `input` with `ngModel` which has `$formatters` and `$parsers` -

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    //format text going to user (model to view)
    ngModel.$formatters.push(function(obj) {
        return obj.first;
    });
}
```

After I make any change in the input , I miss this model on the scope , mean - `{{person.first}}` display nothing .

Here is the full code -

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
     myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
      $scope.person = {
    first: 'Alice',
    last: 'Bob'
   }
     })
  .directive('myDrtv',function(){
   return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
     var _ngModel = ngModel;
     //format text going to user (model to view)
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(obj) {
      return obj.first;
     });
     //format text from the user (view to model)
     ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
      return value;
        });
    }
        
   }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   Name : <input my-drtv  ng-model="person" type="text"><br>
   {{person.first}}
     </div>
  
 </div>
```

How could I change the input and still see it in `{{person.first}}` ?

**Please don't answer me change it to `ng-model="person.first"` I looking solution with - `ng-model="person"`**

Answer (score 1):

Change your input to the following:

```
<input my-drtv ng-model="person.first" type="text">
```

They way you have it, you are clobbering `person` and changing it from an object to a string.

**Edit:**  If you want to keep first name and last name separate, then do something like this:

```
<input my-drtv ng-model="fullname" type="text">
```

and then in `link`, watch for changes and update `person`:

```
scope.$watch('fullname', function(nv) {
  person.first = extractFirstName(nv);
  person.last = extractLastName(nv);
});
```

(I left it to you to supply the `extract` functions).

Comment: thanks for notice me it changed from object to string .

Comment: @URL87, explain *why* you want it to be that way. This is not a typical use of $formatters and $parsers

Comment: I updated my answer on the assumption that you want to be able to use a single edit field for both the first and last name.